# the definition of differential of a Hamiltonian vector field

Tags: differential-geometry, symplectic-geometry, morse-theory

In Audin's book Morse theory and Floer homology, they claim:

> Proposition 6.1.5. Let $H$ be a function on $\mathbb {R^{2n}}$, so that $X_H$ is the Hamiltionian
> field on $\mathbb {R^{2n}}$. If      $|dX_H|_{  L^2 }< 2π$, then the only solutions of period 1 of the
> Hamiltonian system associated with H are the constant solutions (critical
> points of H).

I wonder what is the definition of $dX_H$ here.

Comment: As everything is in $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$, I guess it could just be the matrix obtained by taking the derivatives of the components of $X_H$, like $\left(\partial_iX^j\right)_{1\leq i,j\leq n}$. This is essentially the Hessian of $H$, if you are using the canonical symplectic form on $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$. Does this interpretation make any sense?

Comment: I think you are right, thank you!